# Firestore Update a document after a query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to insert an object to an existing document (the latest document of the collection).

I do the query and if the document is not full I insert the new object into the array (by updating the document).

```
admin.firestore().collection('LinkPages').orderBy("sequence", "desc").limit(1).get()
   .then(function (linkPagesRef) { 
      linkPagesRef.forEach(function(doc) {
         const linkDocument = doc.data();
            const sequence = doc.data().sequence;
            if(linkDocument.links.length > 19)
            {
               functions.logger.info("Document full. Need to create one more");
            }
            else
            {
               functions.logger.info("Document not full. reuse it : ", linkDocument);
               doc.update({ links: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(youtubeData)})
               .then(function (docRef) { response.status(200).send("Ok"); })
               .catch(function (error) { functions.logger.info("Error adding document: ", error); response.status(500).send("Internal error"); });
            }
      });
    })
   .catch(function (error) { functions.logger.info("Error getting LinksPages document: ", error); response.status(500).send("Internal error"); });
```

But At execution I have the error :

```
{"severity":"INFO","message":"Error getting LinksPages document:  TypeError: doc.update is not a function\n
```

It seems the firestore API is not really consistent and depending on how you get the documents reference you dont have the same available functions.

Comment: I would recommend keeping the [library documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/) handy to check which methods are provided by each type/interface.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the update function on the `DocumentReference`;

instead of this

```
doc.update({ links: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(youtubeData)})
```

use

```
doc.ref.update({ links: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(youtubeData)})
```

the `ref` field gives you the `DocumentReference`, with this in hand you could perform any action over the document!